# Can i find the address from longitude and latitude without using wifi in android?

Tags: android

i know it can be found using internet. But i don't wanna use ***internet***.
 any other option ?

Comment: I am not aware of any offline reverse geocoding database, in part because it would be rather large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No..It is not possible to get Address from Lat-Lang without internet because google also do geocoding

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

this getFromLocation() method should be run in asynTask and with internet then it gives desired result.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Internet permission also need